# jQuery Cycle With Rotate not working with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had implemented this jQuery Cycle with Rotate and Tabs in a previous application and it ran without any problem because the rotate method was included within jQuery UI.  My previous app used jQuery 1.6

Now I am trying to implement this in a .NET application that is Bootstrap enabled, I'm using jQuery 1.11.2 and Bootstrap 3.

There is an issue because rotate method has been removed from jQuery UI Tabs.

So I added jquery-ui-tabs-rotate.js

Chrome Console shows 2 errors:
1.  Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined from rotate
2.  Another issue is:  $(...).tabs is not a function

`$("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: "toggle" } }).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);`

Here is the [Test Page](http://www.petcenters.com/Green)

I also tried to add the latest Cycle CDN which didn't fix the problem:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle/3.03/jquery.cycle.all.min.js"></script>
```

I was wondering if anyone knows why this jQuery Cycle Tabs isn't firing?

I simplified the Code, removing the other JavaScript made no difference:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#featured > ul").tabs({ fx: { opacity: "toggle" } }).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `rotate` method has been removed from jQuery UI Tabs, as you can see by this error message appearing in the console of your page:

```
Uncaught Error: no such method 'rotate' for tabs widget instance
```

Doing a search reveals that [this method was removed](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#removed-rotate-method) from jQuery UI Core.  It looks like you can implement a [third-party extension](https://github.com/cmcculloh/jQuery-UI-Tabs-Rotate) to fix this.

Comment: the Console indicates: Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined from rotate, what is 'undefined' ?

Comment: It looks like jQuery is no longer available, so calling `$.fn.tabs` is giving you an error since `$` is now undefined.

Comment: It's not available on your [Green](http://www.petcenters.com/Green) page.  Open the console and type `$`, and you'll see it's undefined.  `jQuery`, on the other hand is defined, so you probably just need to reference that instead of `$`, or else remove some `noConflict` code that you may have added.

Comment: Yep, looks like you're calling `jQuery.noConflict()`, which is making `$` undefined.

Comment: I think that fixed 1 problem. so I'm calling cycle first and then tabs-rotate, but it still appears that I'm missing something.

Comment: You are importing the jquery script, but not the jquery-ui script, so the `tabs` function does not exist.

Comment: Then you won't be able to do what you want to do.

Comment: I have read that there are conflicts with Bootstrap and jQuery UI, so I'm not clear if I can use this jQuery UI.  Perhaps I will just use the Coda Slider that exist on other pages.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure thing!  If you've got an existing tool that works on another page, I'd probably just stick to that. :)